# Piping second or higher argument in native pipe

Tags: r, pipe

by `magrittr`'s pipe (`%>%`) this code works;

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

a <- sample(LETTERS[1:30],5)

a %>% gsub('A','-',x = .)
```

but in R's native or "built in" pipe I can't pipe with dot, this one doesn't work;

```
set.seed(1)

a <- sample(LETTERS[1:30],5)

a |> gsub('A','-',x = .)
```

How can we pass non-first arguments by native R pipe ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The R pipe passes the supplied object to the first *unnamed* argument. If you name the other arguments, it will be passed correctly. For `gsub()`, this looks like the following:

```
a |> gsub(pattern = 'A', replacement = '-')
# "Y" "D" "G" "-" "B"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the native pipe's placeholder, `_`:

```r
a |> gsub('A','-', x = _)
#[1] "Y" "D" "G" "-" "B
```

Comment: With `_` placeholder you need to pass the name of the argument that will receive the `_` placeholder. Like `x = _` in above case.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass the LHS to something other than the first unnamed argument you can use an anonymous function, you just have to make it a function call.

```r
set.seed(1)

a <- sample(LETTERS[1:30],5)

a |> (\(.) gsub('A', '-', x = .))()
#> [1] "Y" "D" "G" "-" "B"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is this a new function notation? Where can I find more examples?